# How to access ADSL modem web-interface thru router?

Tags: networking, router, ip, modem, adsl

I have 3 devices in my network:

1. D-Link router (fixed IP 192.168.0.1, DHCP enabled)
2. ADSL modem (fixed IP 192.168.0.2, DHCP disabled; bridging mode, PPPoE)
3. PC (dynamic IP)

If I connect the modem to the WAN port of my router, then I can not access web-interface of modem from the PC browser (ping also doesn't work).
If I connect it to the LAN port, then web-interface is available, but internet doesn't work. 
What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation at home. My ADSL modem (supplied by my ISP) has a web interface and so does my wireless router (2wire).
I have assigned different IP addresses for my router and ADSL under the same subnet.
Now I'm able to access the modem web interface as well as the routers' home page. The ADSL modem is connected to the uplink port of my wireless router.
ADSL modem - 192.168.0.1
Wireless router - 192.168.0.100
PC - Dynamic IP
I do not remember the IP addresses quite so well - but this is how I got both wired up and configured